# How to use CityHash128 in c++ code?

Tags: c++, static-linking, g++4.8

I am trying to use google's cityhash hashing function. I am unable to link it to my c++ code. I have installed cityHash and it has generated libcityhash.la, etc files in my /usr/local/lib.

I am setting LD_LIB_LIBRARY=/usr/local/lib, but it doesn't seem to link to these files.

CODE:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
int main()
{
    std::ifstream file("dev/urandom");
    char buff[4096];
    file.read(buff, 4096);
    const uint128 hashed = CityHash128(buff,4096);
    file.close();
```

}

Compiling:
    `g++  -o city cityHash.cpp`

Error:
    **/tmp/cctSoHTX.o: In function main:
cityHash.cpp:(.text+0x73): undefined reference to `CityHash128(char const*, unsigned long)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status**

I include "city.h" and trying to compile it as follows:

`g++ -I /usr/local/include/ -L/usr/local/lib -llibcityhash.a cityHash.cpp -o city`

But i m still getting :undefined reference to `CityHash128(char const*, unsigned long)' –

Comment: If your code compiles, which it must have to get to the linker error, then you presumably don't need any more includes. Although I'm baffled as to how that code could compile.

Comment: Could you post the actual code and command line that products that error message?

Comment: I include "city.h" and trying to compile it as follows: g++  -I /usr/local/include/  -L/usr/local/lib -llibcityhash.a  cityHash.cpp -o city. But i m still getting :undefined reference to `CityHash128(char const*, unsigned long)'

Comment: You probably SHOULD use some header-file, but compiler clearly figures out what you wanted - you do, however, need to link to a libary of some sort, `-lcityhash` or something like that.

Comment: Also, it's probably better to EDIT your original post, rather than write command lines and such as comments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, it's the good old "order makes a difference". Instead of:

```
g++ -I /usr/local/include/ -L/usr/local/lib /usr/local/lib/libcityhash.a cityHash.cpp -o city
```

you should do:

```
g++ -I /usr/local/include/ -L/usr/local/lib  cityHash.cpp -o city -lcityhash
```

(libraries and object files are processed in the order of appearance in the command line, and since none of the code so far has used anything from the library when you list it, nothing gets include from that library - then when you get to the actual code that does use it, you don't give the linker the library after it, so it can't find the symbol - note that this is dependant on the behaviour of the linker, so the same rules may not apply in for example a MS Visual Studio compiler/linker setup)

Comment: AFAIK MSVC doesn't suffer from this limitation, and can link anything as long as all symbols are present. IOW, no matter the dependency graph, MSVC can link it, even if the graph is cyclic.